# Supermicro BIOS recovery - SUPER.ROM

Tags: bios, supermicro

I have a [Supermicro X9SCL+-F](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C202_C204/X9SCL_-F.cfm) motherboard that I flashed a beta BIOS to, then the flash went bad when I tried to flash back to the latest stable. I am attempting to recover using their SUPER.ROM recovery from a flash drive without success.

I read in the manual that if I hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Home</kbd>  while powering on the server I can do a BIOS recovery from a flash drive.

I hold down those keys, hear the desired two beeps and I can see the activity LED on the flash drive activate. Unfortunately, instead of the monitor turning on and allowing a BIOS recovery as the manual indicates, I hear five beeps, followed shortly after by 3 beeps. I grabbed the latest BIOS from their site ([x9scm2.508.zip](http://www.supermicro.com/about/policies/disclaimer.cfm?url=/support/resources/getfile.aspx?ID=1744)) and extracted it to my flash drive and renamed it to SUPER.ROM. Their instructions are not clear if any ROM can serve as the SUPER.ROM file, or if I need a special SUPER.ROM file to initiate the recovery at which time I can supply a known good ROM.

Does anyone have any expertise in ROM recovery for Supermicro boards? Am I missing some key step? Can any known good ROM file function as the SUPER.ROM file for recovery?

Comment: I had to do this on a laptop a few times.  When I did it, I kept being impatient and not waiting for the BIOS to restore the firmware and kept interupting it.  It took a good 90 seconds for it to finally finish.  It is curious to note that I didn't get any display other than a flashing num lock and caps lock lights.

I can't answer your question about the name of the file specifically, but I do know that in my case the name was very important.

Comment: The reason why there is no display is because you need a working bios to initialize the display hardware; the special recovery routine probably has just enough code to do its job. I haven't done this procedure in a long time (when I did, it read the recovery BIOS from a floppy!). I'm pretty sure any BIOS can be used but check with support if you're unsure. I always found the Supermicro email support to be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally got some answers from their tech support, though it didn't end up working and it honestly sounded more like "suggestions" than actual facts... regardless:

- The five beeps likely means "process failure" in this case - whatever that means.
- The three beeps could possibly mean RAM failure. I strongly doubt this as I let the RAM burn in with memtest+ for about 72 hours. Doesn't mean something isn't wrong - just doubtful.
- For what it is worth, I was told that the format of the flash drive didn't matter between FAT12, FAT16 and FAT32 - I tried both FAT16 and FAT32 without success.
- I was told that the name of the file is case sensitive, and should be SUPER.ROM in all caps.
- I was also told that any known good BIOS image could be used as a source, just renamed to SUPER.ROM

I hope this helps someone else in the future. After about six weeks of emailing back and forth with their tech support and attempting different things with this board - I finally gave up troubleshooting it and just sent it in for an RMA and purchased a different board. Anyone want to buy a refurbished Supermicro board?

Comment: What file system did you use if nothing of FAT-XX works?

Comment: Thanks for answer, my war is still continuing. Now I'm trying FAT16, since RMA is very far from me ...

Answer (score 1):

Get mainboards with a "-F" in the product name. Then you have IPMI and can even flash a faulty BIOS. It requires a key from Supermicro to activate this feature which is not for free, but you can order a demo key which helps in this case. You get it relatively quick within 1-3 workdays.

The 2nd flash area can also be fully impacted by a faulty flash process, therefore the trick with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>HOME</kbd> does not work.

At the end nothing will work, as a faulty flashed BIOS results in a fully dead machine. All that helps here is to go via IPMI. Then you are glad having spend the xx bucks more on a board with IPMI. Otherwise you would have to send the board damaged to supermicro.

Comment: This question is a bit old, so my memory is perhaps not perfect of this event any longer, but as I recall I could not reach the board via IPMI either. I believe the IPMI implementation on this board will only allow for IPMI firmware flashes not BIOS upgrades though. I would have to double check.

Comment: This is partially true information. Not all "-F" supermicro motherboards support updating via IPMI  (or web management interface). Desktop motherboards do not support that at all. Example: X11SAE-F